# AlamoFire 4.0 + SwiftyJSON Unwrapping deeply nested JSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm having issues parsing the JSON I'm getting back from the Wiki API.

Podfile:

```html
platform :ios, ’10.0’

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target 'GemFinder' do

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0’
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/appsailor/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'

end
```

Swift Code:

```html
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class WikiAPI: NSObject {
    
    func MineralRequest(minID: (String)) {
        
        Alamofire.request("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=\(minID)&exintro=1&prop=pageimages%7Cextracts&format=json&pithumbsize=300", parameters: ["query": "pages"]).responseJSON { response in
            
            if let values = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                
                let json = JSON(values)
                
                // Returns null
                print("otherJSON: \(json["query"]["pages"][0]["extract"])")
                
                
                let JSONvalues = values as NSDictionary
                print("JSONvalues: \(JSONvalues)")

                // This is also working to retrieve everything from below "query"
                let parse = JSONvalues.object(forKey: "query")
                print("Parse: \(parse)")
                
                let queryValues = values["query"]
                
                // Returns nested "pages" object, but I need to go deeper.
                print("queryvalues: \(queryValues?["pages"])")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to get a response, of course, and trying to go deeper, but I keep getting null values when trying to unwrap.

What am I missing? Here's an image of the tree. I'm trying to pull title, images and the extract out.

[JSON response preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T4Gg.png)

Following this format, as seen here, still yields null values. Parameters didn't seem to benefit either: [How do I access a nested JSON value using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287836/how-do-i-access-a-nested-json-value-using-alamofire-and-swiftyjson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"pages" value is a dictionary so using `[0]` on it won't work, you need to use the key instead:

```
print("otherJSON: \(json["query"]["pages"]["1895477"]["extract"])")
```

Or if there are many items in pages and you want them all you can iterate through it like:

```
let pages = json["query"]["pages"]
for (_,page) in pages {
    print(page["extract"])
}
```

Comment: The first part works, but after more investigation, I noticed that pages.values is throwing an error. Says that JSON has no member "values". Might there be another way to do this without converting the JSON to something else?

Comment: @softdownfeathers You're welcome:)  I updated the answer with the correct loop syntax for SwiftyJSON.